# Coin Collectors SE site?

Tags: support, area-51

Is there an SE dedicated to coin collectors?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by coin collector?

Comment: OK, I give, what does programming have to do with coin collecting?

Comment: Ok, I lost you there. Maybe you thought, 'Is there a Stack Exchange site for numismatics?'. Is it so?

Comment: @Lance: you don't get a coin for each line of code you write?!

Comment: If you don't have enough coins yet, jump up and bump your head against something.

Comment: [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) has the [`super-mario-bros`](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-bros) tag. ;)

Comment: Goran Jovic, yes, I have been asking about Numismatics. There are a lot of questions to ask on that topic. Michael Mrozek provided the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Could someone pleas edit this (tag -> SE site) and stop making fun of him?

Comment: The number of people confused by such a simple question is astounding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming Goran is right and you're asking about an SE site instead of a tag, there's a proposal for [Coin Collectors](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6515/coin-collectors) on Area 51

Comment: How exactly is "numismatics" more clear than coin collecting?  You can collect coins for numismatic value and/or simple stacking.  The OP's post is 100% clear and concise.  There are just too many programmers here acting as experts in a field they have zero comprehension of and I find this behavior repulsive.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I don't think anybody argued that numismatics was clearer; the confusion came from the question originally asking about tags instead of Stack Exchange sites before it was [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/73914/revisions). Also this was 12 years ago.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the clarification.  I will leave this comment here as it clarifies what happened over time.