# Is there a Stack Exchange site for philately and deltiology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange site for **philately** and **deltiology**? (Those are collection and study of postage stamps and postage cards.) If not, is there a site where I could ask about them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coin Collectors SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73914/coin-collectors-se-site)

Comment: The OP is asking about stamp and postcard collecting, not coins @πάνταῥεῖ.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How come numismatics and philately are related?

Comment: @Clicker I could think of a site designed for general questions related to collect things of all kind. I don't think it would be worth to have a separate site for each and any field. People collect all kind of things, coins, minerals, art, etc. Any of these could well manifest as tags. And no, there's no site actually as far I'm aware of.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards ^^

Comment: That's probably why that Area51 proposal had gone: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6515/coin-collectors

Comment: I well notice that there's a difference between collecting coins or stamps. Anyhow, what's in common is asking for a site dedicated to a community of collectors, no matter which specific field. @benisuǝqbackwards

Comment: @Clicker Could you give some specific examples of questions you'd like to ask at such site please? Maybe we could find a surrogate as apparently no such site exists, or ever made it up through Area51.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As πάντα ῥεῖ [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311626/323179) there is no site that would accept all questions about stamps and stamp collecting.

However, there is a History site where you could ask historical questions about stamps. In fact, there is already one question there about stamps: [Which George V stamp would be used for a letter sent from London to Sweden in 1919/1920?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/37832/31542) The History site has more questions about [coins](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numismatics), so you might get a better idea of what makes a good question by looking at that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there were already Area51 proposals for such sites earlier, but none of these made it through the approval process. Here's an example shown from my google search:

[image]

If you follow the link you'll see this:

[image]

So no, there doesn't seem to be an appropriate site to ask questions specifc about collection of stamps or cards.

---

I can't really tell why these Area51 proposals were declined, but I can imagine that such community would highly suffer from spam, questions about 3rd party resources, or users to get opinions about their collections, not to mention all kind of trading announcements abusage.